# Ionic Framework and Firebase 3.x version: This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an iOS app using Ionic Framework and Firebase. I have updated Firebase SDK to version 3.x in my project. What I am trying to do is to authenticate the user with Facebook on a real device. Everything works fine when I test it on a browser. However, whenever I run on a real iOS device, I always get the following error:

**This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.**

On Firebase, I have already added "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" to my authorized domain list. So I am not sure what to do right now.

For your information, I do not use WKWebView in my project.

Does anybody here can tell me how I can solve this? Please advice.

Comment: I think we should add the app's domain in the "OAuth redirect domains" section in Firebase, but I don't know which is the app's domain when running on a device.
- document.location.host and window.location.host are blank

Comment: You need to update everything following these [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#import_your_project_to_the_firebase_console_numbered) from the firebase doc! [Credits](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-framework-and-firebase-v3-auth-error-this-domain-is-not-authorized-for-oauth-operations-for-your-firebase-project/52764)

Comment: Facing same issue in React-native on android or iOs Plateform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error `"This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console."` only prevents `signInWithPopup()` `signInWithRedirect()` `linkWithPopup()` and `linkWithRedirect()` operations from working. Every other function, including `signInWithCredential()`, should work.

I believe that you are seeing this error because ionic apps do not have a real domain, and this is a requirement for the 4 functions I mentioned above.

The solution to your problem would be to ignore the error (it is just informational) and not use `signInWithPopup` `signInWithRedirect` `linkWithPopup` or `linkWithRedirect`. Instead, use a library for OAuth such as [ngCordovaOAuth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth) and then use `auth().signInWithCredential(...)` (see example instructions for Twitter [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_manually)).

Comment: You are right, this works.

I prefer using a plugin to prompt a native login like cordova-plugin-facebook4 or twitter-connect-plugin.

It would be great to have a workaround to use Firebase's v3 login without installing plugins.

Comment: Glad it worked! And definitely, that is a very interesting feature request, I will pass it to the team.

Comment: Yep, this works. Thanks a lot alfongj. I also sent an email to ask Firebase about this issue and they too suggest to use an Oauth library and then use signInWithCredential(). For your information, a feature request regarding this issue has been submitted. =)

Comment: Great to hear! Could you mark this as the accepted answer, so other developers find it when they search for it?

Comment: Sure, just did. Tyvm.

Comment: Firebase has still not addressed this. I do not want to install cordova plugins just to get this to work.  Using firebase with any hybrid style app (cordova, ionic, phonegap, etc) will fail like this when trying to authenticate via social networks using JUST firebase.

Comment: The problem is SMS and other sign in methods sometimes require an authroised domain with things like reCaptcha. So you can't just ignore it; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue but i solved it by creating new firebase project.

Comment: I tried your method but didn't get any luck. I am using Ionic v.1.7.14 and Firebase 3.x. When calling firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) on iOS, a new pop shows up then disappears immediately. =(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my temporary solution:

I import both Firebase SDK v.2.x and Firebase SDK 3.x in my ionic project. I use version 2.x for Facebook authentication on iOS then I use version 3.x to get access to all new features on Firebase such as Storage and so on.

Hopes this helps.