# Firebase Google Auth in Electron App gives "location.protocol" must be http, https

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

```
<button id="signin_with_google_button">sign in</button>
<script>
  var firebase = require("firebase");
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAwp7hhcZGyNfZOY8AOeIrpzkzL69quiS0",
    authDomain: "https://sdsdss-efefx22.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://sdsdss-efefx22.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sdsdss-efefx22",
    storageBucket: "sdsdss-efefx22.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "3232323"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  document.querySelector('#signin_with_google_button')
          .addEventListener('click', () => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){  
        console.log("Google result", result);
      }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log("Google Error", error);
      });
  });
</script>
```

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is
>   running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or
>   chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

firebase version:

```
"firebase": "4.6.2",
```

PS: I have gone through [location.protocol" must be http or https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949085/location-protocol-must-be-http-or-https)
but no one seems to suggest any work around for electron.

**Update:**

Tried implicit email auth, it works as suggested [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWS0ocfszmE)

But firebaseui still doesn't work as electron in not officially supported, explained [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/issues/30#issuecomment-389751539) . Even though it is not officially supported but I am sure there will be workarounds, keeping the question open for people to suggest workarounds.

Comment: Any success for this?

Comment: Any success with this?